# Is there a situation that when range.location > targetString.length, range.length !=0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange

1. Is there a situation possible that when `range.location > targetString.length` then `range.length !=0`?
2. What's the best way to judge whether an range variable exists?

Comment: You need to show the code, this doesn't makes sense to anyone. What do you mean by `targetString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invalid `NSRange` has the `location` member set to `NSNotFound` (which is `NSIntegerMax`), so:

1. Yes, when the range is invalid, however in that case the `length` member should be ignored anyway.
2. If by "exists" you mean "valid", it's when `location != NSNotFound`.

Comment: So whether an NSRange is effective just decided by location ,is that right ?

Comment: Well, is there a situation that when location == NSNotFound, length != 0?

Comment: That would be undefined; the contract (as far as I'm aware) is that if `location == NSNotFound` then `length` should be ignored.